# Who is the owner of ETH zone?

Tags: ens, name-registrar

As I understand,  **.eth** domain zone is a smart-contract. Does the owners of this smart contract delete record about .eth domain?

Comment: Can you rephrase "Does the owners of this smart contract delete record about .eth domain?" Are you asking if the root key holders have ever explicitly changed an owner on a record under `.eth`? They had to set an auction contract as the owner of `eth` itself, and will eventually update the owner of `eth` to a new contract.

Answer (score 3):

The [Ethereum Name Service (ENS)](https://ens.domains/) is, in fact, powered by a smart contract. This contract handles everything from domain purchases to resolvers.

The ENS was designed to be upgraded in the future (this helps the founders come up with better was to prevent squatting, and include other upgrades along the process). Because of this, the owner of the contract is a multisig wallet that cannot simply be changed easily. There must be consensus among the key holders.

From the ENS website, "To facilitate the possibility of upgrades and maintenance, and in exceptional circumstances to handle problems with ENS, the ENS root will initially be owned by a multisig, with members of the Ethereum dev community as keyholders. In the long term, we would like to see the root multisig replaced by some form of distributed decision making process, but developing such a process will require time, thought, and care, which we anticipate will be a longer term effort than the development of the permanent .eth registrar."

These root holders are as follows:

- Dan Finlay
- Nick Johnson
- Jarrad Hope
- Piper Merriam
- Taylor Monahan
- Vlad Zamfir